# Как выложить playfraimwork проект на хостинг

Tags: playframework

Добрый день. Написал небольшой сайт на playfraimwork, можете подсказать как его можно выложить на хостинговый сервер. В частности меня интересует хостинг jelastic. Ни один мануал по выкладке не работает. Я даже не могу создать war, чтобы просто выложить его на хостинг. Помогите, может кто сталкивался с таким или знает что посчитать?

Answer (score 1):

Команда play dist должна war файл создать

Comment: у меня данная каоманда создает zip, если его просто переименовать в war и выложить то он не может нормально развернуться, наверное еще что-то надо прописывать?

Comment: У вас Play 2.0 наверно, там больше нельзя просто так взять и создать war файл. Попробуйте этот plugin, если надо на чужой хостинг выложить https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin
Если есть свой свой сервер, то результат play dist нужно выложить и запускать через скрипт start внутри архива.

Comment: я сделал все что было написанно в описании play2-war но выскакивают ошибки и как их побороть я не знаю

Answer (score 1):

Соберите локально war файл.
А далльше на сервак можно закинуть мавеном.
Например для томката можно использовать встроеный менеджер:

```
 <plugin>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.6</version>
            <configuration>
               <container>
                  <containerId>tomcat6x</containerId>
                  <type>remote</type>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <type>runtime</type>
                    <properties>
                       <cargo.tomcat.manager.url>
                            http://localhost:8080/manager
                       </cargo.tomcat.manager.url>
                       <cargo.remote.username>dsfa</cargo.remote.username>
                       <cargo.remote.password>dfsfad</cargo.remote.password>
                     </properties>
                 </configuration>
                 <deployer>
                      <type>remote</type>
                      <deployables>
                         <deployable>
                              <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                              <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                              <type>war</type>
               <properties>
                   <context>${project.artifactId}</context>
                </properties>
             </deployable>
        </deployables>
     </deployer>
    </configuration>
```

</plugin>

http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin

Comment: Я конечно понимаю что вопрос тупой, но я даже не знаю куда это писать.

Comment: Во первых нужно попробовать собрать war файл командой
play war webapp -o temp --%production --zip

Comment: команды war нет, пробовал то что вы предлагаете не работает

Comment: то есть я правильно понял что если у меня не выделенный сервер, я вообще не смогу  запустить playframework проект?

Comment: нет нет, конешн сможете

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play вот статьяч каак задеплоить простейшее приложение

Comment: это же можно найти в оф. доках http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0.1/guide1

Comment: а вы так делали? у вас работает? просто у меня не получилось и туда его запульнуть.

Comment: просто я думал что Вы используете сборкеу проекта Мавеном, как я обычно поступаю)